# Adding reference information to a skos:Concept

Tags: rdf, semantic-web, skos

If I have a skos:Concept that represents some scientific term:

```
PREFIX ex: <http://a.example/ex1#>
PREFIX skos: <http://www.w3.org/2004/02/skos/core#>
PREFIX desiredresource: <http://what.im.looking.for/>

ex:Chelation a skos:Concept ;
  skos:prefLabel "Chelation"@en ;
  skos:definition "a type of bonding of ions and molecules to metal ions."@en;
  desiredresource:reference "https://goldbook.iupac.org/terms/view/C01012" .
```

What is the recommended way to represent:

- reference information (such as journal articles) from which the definition was obtained or derived.
- Resources that provide more information for the reader.

So far I've considered:

- `dcat:source` : as a 'reference' from which the definition was obtained

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The elements of the SKOS vocabulary can be used in combination with other elements, such as elements of the Dublin Core. And you can use from dublin core terms *references* or *relation*

```
PREFIX ex: <http://a.example/ex1#>
PREFIX skos: <http://www.w3.org/2004/02/skos/core#>
PREFIX dc: <http://purl.org/dc/terms/>
  ex:Chelation a skos:Concept ;
  skos:prefLabel "Chelation"@en ;
  skos:definition "a type of bonding of ions and molecules to metal ions."@en;
  dc:references "https://goldbook.iupac.org/terms/view/C01012" .
```

you can see details about dublin core elements [here](https://www.dublincore.org/specifications/dublin-core/dcmi-terms/)

Comment: Awesome, "references" and 'relation" look like exactly what I was looking for. My only improvement of the answer would be to include the definition of each.  References: A related resource that is referenced, cited, or otherwise pointed to by the described resource.  Relation: A related resource.

Comment: And there is also the `source` element which may prove useful for such cases.